# Best solution to display comics on a website

Tags: javascript, pdf, web-development, react

I am drawing a comic and I want to share it on my personal site. Problem is I don't know any cool js / reactjs plugins to create a comic reader.

I want something smooth and cool, that ideally would adapt to the size of the screen and switch between double page reading to scroll view (the first would be great to simulate immersive reading, the second would help a lot mobile reading).

Do you know any github project, or even paid script that could help me?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

[IDR Solutions](https://www.idrsolutions.com/) have a PDF to HTML5 converter that would create a reasonably cool page turning HTML5 version of the PDF when I tried it a year or so back.  It had quite a few options for the HTML 5 rendering so you might want to try it out.  Find a decent couple of PDF examples, use the tool to create the HTML5 paged versions of it and see if it suits your requirements.